# How do I create a for loop and while loop for a program with 5 different functions in c?

Tags: c, visual-studio

I'm trying to write a program that converts Fahrenheit to Celsius and vice versa based on user menu selections and inputs, and I want the results to display a table based on the range and resolution inputted by user, but I'm stuck on writing the for loop and the while loop I was instructed to use for the two display functions. I'm new to programming with a language like c and I've been working on this for 3 days, so any tips/suggestions would be helpful.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#pragma warning(disable:4996)

float calc_FtoC(float Fahrenheit);
void display_FtoC(int start, int stop, int step);
float calc_CtoF(float Celsius);
void display_CtoF(int start, int stop, int step);


void main(void)
{
char select;
int start, stop, step;


do
{
    printf("Enter A to Convert Fahrenheit to Celsius.\n");
    printf("Enter B to Convert Celsius to Fahrenheit.\n");
    printf("Enter Q to Quit.\n");
    printf("You entered -> ");
    scanf("%c", &select);
    while (getchar() != '\n');
    select = toupper(select);
    
    printf("Enter the highest temp to convert: \n");
    scanf("%d", &start);
    while (getchar() != '\n');
    printf("Enter lowest temp to convert: \n");
    scanf("%d", &stop);
    while (getchar() != '\n');
    printf("Enter increments: \n");
    scanf("%d", &step);
    while (getchar() != '\n');
    
    switch (select)
    {
    case 'A':
        display_FtoC(start, stop, step);
        break;
    case 'B':
        display_CtoF(start, stop, step);
        break;
    case 'Q':
        break;
    default:
        printf("You did not enter a correct selection!\n");
        break;
    }
} while (select != 'Q');
}

float calc_FtoC(float Fahrenheit)
{
float calc_f2c;
calc_f2c = 0.556 * Fahrenheit - 17.78;

return calc_f2c;
}

void display_FtoC(int start, int stop, int step)
{
  // This is where the for loop for Fahrenheit to Celsius conversion is supposed to be
}

float calc_CtoF(float Celsius)
{
float calc_c2f;
calc_c2f = 1.8 * Celsius + 32;

return calc_c2f;
}

void display_CtoF(int start, int stop, int step)
{
  // This is where the while loop is supposed to be for Celsius to Fahrenheit conversion
}
```

Comment: 1. Define the specification of the program to write. 2. Write a program according to the specification. 3. Test and debug what you wrote.

Comment: Some of the specification to define: How will the "table" look like? What should be done if `stop - start` is not divisible by `step`? What should be done when `step` is zero?

Comment: Remove _all_ `while (getchar() != '\n');` Then, `scanf("%c", &select);` --> `scanf(" %c", &select);` (note the extra space in the format).

Comment: With these changes all `scanf` will skip over whitespace (e.g. newlines) which is what you want.